# Cant display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i am writing a React application to fetch and display data and sort it according to popularity but its not working

this is the api link - https://s3.amazonaws.com/open-to-cors/assignment.json

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://s3.amazonaws.com/open-to-cors/assignment.json"
        );
        const print = await response.json();
        const ans = Object.values(print);
         const sortedProducts = ans.data.sort(
           (a, b) => b.Popularity - a.Popularity
         );
        setProducts(ans);
        // setProducts(print);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Product List</h1>
      <ul>
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <strong>Title:</strong> {product.title},<strong>Price:</strong>{" "}
            {product.Price},<strong>Popularity:</strong>
            {product.Popularity}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

i tried to convert fetched data into object but didnt work

Comment: It's not clear what isn't working here.  Are you having trouble getting the data or are you having trouble converting into the format you'd like?

Comment: i printed the {print} in console it worked fine but when use map to do it , it doesnt work says "products.map is not a function " so i converted it to object and now the webpage desent display anything except the text in `strong`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert the object keys into an array using `Object.entries()`.
after that sort the result.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://s3.amazonaws.com/open-to-cors/assignment.json'
        );
        const print = await response.json();

        const productArray = Object.entries(print.products).map(([id, product]) => ({
          id,
          ...product
        }));
        

        const sortedProducts = productArray.sort((a, b) => b.popularity - a.popularity);
        setProducts(sortedProducts);
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Product List</h1>
      <ul>
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <strong>Title:</strong> {product.title},<strong>Price:</strong>{' '}
            {product.price},<strong>Popularity:</strong>
            {product.popularity}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

also here dont use captal letter

```
<li key={index}>
            <strong>Title:</strong> {product.title},<strong>Price:</strong>{" "}
            {product.Price},<strong>Popularity:</strong>
            {product.Popularity}
          </li>
```